# How to simplify multiple @font-face styles

Tags: css

I'm trying to simplify current css and can't find out, is there a way to make it simplier.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot');
    src: url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('OpenSans-Regular-webfont.svg#open_sansregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}


@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    src: url('OpenSans-Italic-webfont.eot');
    src: url('OpenSans-Italic-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('OpenSans-Italic-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('OpenSans-Italic-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('OpenSans-Italic-webfont.svg#open_sansitalic') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

On the one hand, they are exactly identical, but on the other hand all files are different.

Am I missing something and there is a way to make this style more simple and clear?

Comment: I don't think you can make it more simpler as all files are for x-browser support.

Comment: If you're only planning on using OpenSans, just use Google's `<link`. `<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Comment: @GavinThomas valid point, but I forgot to mention that I need them ofline and there are other fonts. But still thank you!